# Scaling invariance of fluid energy

Tags: energy, fluid-dynamics, invariants, scale-invariance

I have read that the incompressible Navier Stokes equation is preserved by the scaling

$$x',y',z'=\lambda x, \lambda y, \lambda z$$
$$t'=\lambda^2 t$$
$$u'=(1/\lambda) u$$

As I understand it, fluid energy is given by

$$\int u^2 dv$$

I am trying to understand what is meant by the claim that the fluid energy is invariant under the scaling $\frac{1}{\lambda^{d/2}}u(\frac{x}{\lambda},\frac{t}{\lambda^2})$ where $d$ is the dimension of space? Could someone explain/derive this scaling invariance of the energy

Comment: Your question is why the integral is invariant under this rescaling? Did you try to see what happens when you perform a rescaling of the coordinates?

Comment: Yes, it worked. the factor comes out with $d=3$ when coordinates are rescaled, thanks